# Harvest AC current by connecting to ground?

Tags: grounding, energy-harvesting

The other day I was curious and I tried the following:

- Set multimeter to AC
- Hold one lead in one hand
- Plug the other lead into ground plug of a house socket
- Multimeter shows ~2V

Does that mean that these 2V can be harvested?  Where are the 2V coming from?  From my body?  How much current should I expect to harvest?   Under what circumstances can I get more/less?

Somewhat related question that I'm curious about: when I'm doing this and a lightning strikes the house will I get electrocuted while holding the ground wire?

Comment: I've no clue how reputable this publication is (never read anything from it before), but I suspect [this energy harvesting article from 2016](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/tswj/2016/3934289/) may have a few things to wonder about. Just googled it for you.

Comment: You don't harvest voltage (or current) but energy.

Comment: Also measure what you're getting on the current range. You'll be lucky to see even 1 uA, giving you 2 W at best. Not very much. And you'll see it varying a lot as you move around and/or you turn appliances on or off. It's coming from AC electric (and/or magnetic) fields radiated from the house wiring and all your appliances.

Comment: ElectroBoom has  a video about something similar to this. [Link](https://www.youtube.com/c/Electroboom/search?query=harvest)

Comment: @user_1818839, I think suggesting to a novice that they switch a multimeter to current range, grab a probe with one hand and stick the other into a mains socket is crazy. Even doing it on voltage range could be lethal if the probes were in the wrong sockets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not only the voltage that matters, it's the current. And if you are holding that meter into air then you have a lot of resistance (over 10^9 ohms) and pFs of capacitance between the meter and other conductors like ground, which means there will only be less than uA available. So yeah it can be harvested, and not enough power to drive even an LED to any reasonable brightness.

As far as lightning goes it depends on the current and the current cannot be predicted

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations! You have created a radio receiver. Your body, the meter leads, and the house ground are the antenna, and the multimeter is serving as the detector. The energy source is all of the radio waves (some natural, some man-made, some coherent, some noise) zipping around the environment at any moment. It is indeed possible to harvest power this way, and some of the [earliest radio receivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_radio) used this ability to power a small earpiece without requiring any batteries or mains connection. The available power is around one billionth of a watt, depending on the strength of radio signals where you are. Pretty cool that such a tiny amount of power, converted into sound, is even perceptible to your ears, isn't it?

---

Okay, I lied. While the radio effect *does* happen, probably most of what you're getting (and most of what the meter is good at registering) is inductive coupling of the 50 or 60 Hz AC from the house wires all around you. This is similar to radio, but it's a "near field" effect instead of a "far field" effect, meaning it decreases very quickly as you get further away from those wires. But:

1. That's a lot less fun to talk about,
2. The amount of power you can practically harvest is similarly small,
3. Any power you *did* get that way would be registered by your electrical meter and show up on your bill; there's nothing "free" about it, unlike radio.

Answer (score -1):

You are reading 'phantom' voltage between your outlet ground and your floor ground. They are theorically at the same potential so that, in theory, shouldn't happen.

However the ground system is also more or less an antenna so it also picking up noise, radio transmissions and so on. The power available is minimal but an high impedance input voltmeter (typical impedance of about 1 megaohm) can read it. Try with a low impedance one (3 kiloohm impedance, nominal, many electrician DVM have a setting for that) and you'll see it disappear.

You *could* harvest some microamps from that but it would be almost the same that harvesting from RF energy in the air (which is actually done)